# NServicebus Publisher/Distributor Unable to communicate with all subscribers/workers?

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus-distributor

We have one distributor/publisher (NSB community version, which is on a domain but recently changed to workgroup mode due to some issues), which communicates to two workers on two different servers (on domain). All of a sudden it is not sending any work to one of the workers where as the worker has sent several acknowledgements which were unacknowledged by the publisher.

Please help - whether this is a bug in NSB host or am i missing something here?

Comment: Do you see messages in the outbound queue of the Distributor machine destined for either machine?

Comment: I can only see one outbound queue on distributor machine outgoing messages, for the only worker working normally.

Comment: Forgot to mention myself and our infra team has done a reinstall of MSMQ using directory services integration and do you want to know what happend???? - The scene got reversed- i.e even now only one worker is active but this time it is another worker than the worker which was causing issues to us till these days. The only difference between these workers is - one worker is hosted on physical machine(inactive now) and other is hosted on a virtual server (which was inactive from past few days)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the issue, it is not related to Nservicebus, rather it is related to network.
The servers were unable to communicate each other due to some security/firewall problems.

Solution is: Adding the host entries of subscribers (worker servers) in the publisher (distributor) has solved the same.